# Customize Superscript as in Songbook

Tags: html, css, appearance

I want to do a songbook in HTML, something like

[image]

I wonder whether this can be easily achieved by some `css` trick on the `<sup>` tag (or similar)

```
<sup>F</sup>Yesterday <sup>Em7</sup>  all my <sup>A7</sup> troubles seemed so <sup>Dm</sup>far away <sup>Dm/C</sup>   

<sup>Bb</sup>now I <sup>C7</sup>need a place to <sup>F</sup>hide away <sup>C</sup>oh <sup>Dm</sup>I <sup>G7</sup>believe in <sup>Bb</sup>yes<sup>F</sup>terday
```

[image]

Now two questions:

1. **Which adjustments should be added to the `<sup>` tag for this to work?** At least it must be higher and must behave as if it occupied no space at all (for example, 'yesterday' should not be divided)
2. **Is there a better trick than using the `<sup>` tag?**

Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a `sup`, I'd suggest a `span` with a data-attribute in a pseudo-element.

The pseudo-element can then be positioned as you desire and provided a suitable line-height is used this all works out fairly dynamically.

Size everything in `em` and:

```css
p {
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
span::after {
  content: attr(data-note);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  color: red;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span data-note="F"></span>Yesterday <span data-note="Em7"></span>all my <span data-note="Dm"></span>troubles seemed so <span data-note="A7"></span>far away
  <br><span data-note="Bb"></span>  <span data-note="Bb"></span>now I <span data-note="C7"></span>need to find a place to <span data-note="F"></span>hide away <span data-note="C"></span>oh <span data-note="Dm"></span>I beli<span data-note="G7"></span>eve in yes<span data-note="Bb"></span>terday
</p>
```

As the span's are empty screenreaders shouldn't have a problem with them (although I'm unsure as whether the `content` is read by screenreaders.

Comment: @Paulie_D Simply amazing. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!!